# Post history markdown diffs overlapping

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

When I look at the history of some post and switch to markdown diff, the left half of the diff overlaps the right part and both continue outside the screen.

For example, [this history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/158829/revisions) looks like this to me (notice the highlighted part and the scrollbar):

[image: History of the linked answer]

This makes the markdown version of the diff pretty much unusable, could this be fixed?
It's most likely some problem with CSS.

This also seems to happen here on meta, but not on Stack Overflow.

I'm using Firefox 14.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: No repro on FF14.0.1, Win7. Perhaps it's a add on messing things up? Any chance you could test this on a vanilla installation of FF?

Comment: That's weird that you can't repro. I tried with a new FF profile (i.e. no extensions) and even tried to disable all plug-ins, but in both cases I still see the problem.

Comment: I also tried it on a completely fresh install of FF in a Win8 CP virtual machine and again, it looks the same, still broken.

Comment: reported recently as a bug at MSO, marked status-completed few hours ago: **[Revision mark-down source diff bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142026/165773)** (might not reach everyone immediately due to [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching))